# How to get a user who pushed the branch using Github API?

Tags: rest, api, github, github-api

I use `https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#get-branch` endpoint
but it doesn't provide any information who is the owner of the branch.

Commit author doesn't fit, because it's just a user who pushed the latest commit.

Any ideas ?